# Android: Imagebutton not displaying as size of actual image

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an image button with an a small image, however I can't seem to be able to get the image to appear on screen as its actual size. It keeps being scaled up to fit the size of the button.

I found some code that appears like it should fix this issue but now its just causing the image not to appear at all.

I am doing it programatically so heres what I have so far.

```
            moreInfo.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
            moreInfo.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
          //had thought that these lines would have fixed it but just cause nothing to display
                moreInfo.setMaxHeight(20);
                moreInfo.setMaxWidth(20);
                moreInfo.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
         //end of
            moreInfoLP.setMargins(2,2,5,0);
            moreInfo.setLayoutParams(moreInfoLP);
```

Comment: Try setting the height/width in the LayoutParams.

Comment: Why are you doing `setBackGroundDrawable(null)`?

Comment: To remove the default image of the button, it was causing what looked like borders around the image

Comment: I'm an idiot, i have since changed the height and width values to something a bit larger and it appears perfect. D'oh!

Comment: Post your solution as an answer and accept :)

Comment: To be fair it probably wouldn't have worked unless I had followed your original suggestion, post yours as an answer and I will accept yours.